# Android studio cannot create a new flutter project

Tags: android, flutter

When I use Android studio to create a new flutter project, the following error occurs:Multiple output directories specified.Try moving --org to be immediately following create.

[Project configuration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnaP1.png)

[Error message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1qnb.png)

The running result of flutter doctor is as follows, the operating system is mac.

[flutter doctor Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DTAI.png)

Comment: did you try to create it in a different location?

Comment: After changing the project directory, the same problem still occurs.

Comment: Please complete the xcode setup first as flutter doctor says. Then check again.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the error message now? After flutter doctor executes successfully.

Comment: Error:Multiple output directories specified.
Try moving --org to be immediately following create

Comment: did you tried to create a new project using command line in fluter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching, I think it's an error in your Android Studio's create command. Try this in your command line

```
flutter create --org com.yourdomain your_app_name
```

If this works, then my assumption is right. From your error message, it is saying that *--org* should be after *create*. I found a similar [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6489) in Github. A clean installation may solve the issue then.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I can successfully create a flutter project using the command line. After Android studio import the project, I can start programming. It is not convenient to reinstall Android studio at the moment, and I will try it later.

Comment: Great to hear. Please mark the answer as accepted then.